# Is there any way to generate Date object in UTC timezone

Tags: javascript, typescript, momentjs

I have a typescript method that expects a Date object and it converts into a local timezone using moment. Now I want to write a unit test for that and to accomplish that I need a Date object in UTC format.

The problem is when I do `new Date()` to get date object it returns date with local timezone

```
Wed Apr 15 2020 11:38:10 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

and since the zone already local my method won't convert it into local again.

```
convertUTCtoLocal(utcDate: Date): Date {
  return new Date(moment.utc(utcDate).local().format());
}
```

I know there are methods like `.toISOString()`, `.toGMTString()` but these return a string I want a Date object

Any idea, what can be done.

Comment: You need to differentiate between a date object and its representation. There is no "date object in UTC timezone". A date is a date, it is the same point in time. You can change the way it gets displayed (local, UTC, whatever).

Comment: I got your point but that is the problem, Now I can't write a unit test around this.

Answer (score 0):

I have just solved this problem like this:

```
//Convert to string and add 'Z' to the end to indicate UTC
const backendDateStr = myDateThatIsUTC.toString() + 'Z' 
//Convert it back to a date object that recognizes that it's 
//in UTC timezone and then to string.
const backendDate = new Date(backendDateStr).toUTCString(); 
//Create a new object (string) that is locale ajusted. 
//(This builds on that your app has the correct locale set already).
const frontendOffsetDate = new Date(backendDate).toLocaleString(); 
//if you want it as a date object, you could do this instead:
const frontendOffsetDate = new Date(new Date(backendDate).toLocaleString());
```

It's hacky but it works.